# Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount Will Not Connect

Tags: powershell, powerbi

I have been struggling to connect to Power BI through PowerShell. If I use 'Login-PowerBI' and then select my username and stored password from the pop-up, it's all fine. But, for automation purposes, I need the login to happen through the code. I have tried the following:

```
Import-Module MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt
Import-Module MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt.Profile

$username = "MyUsername"
$password = "MyPassword" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $password)

[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -Credential $credential
```

I have installed the above modules.
I get the following error:

```
WARNING: (False) MSAL 4.25.0.0 MSAL.Desktop Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.19044.0 [...] Exception type: Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalClientE
xception
, ErrorCode: parsing_wstrust_response_failed
```

I was unable to find a solution. I am trying to connect to the service of a large corporation. Is it possible that there are some restriction in place?

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Most likely your account is with MFA enabled, so this will not work. In general, in such scenarios, you should use service principal for authentication, not user account.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Unfortunately I cannot use service principal as it is forbidden by the organization.
Yes, my account uses MFA. Is there no way to avoid this issue?